# How do I move the past n commits to main, into a separate branch, with git?

Tags: git, branch

say that i've been working in master, and i've just realized that maybe my last few commits (say, 15 of them) probably belong on a branch.

how do i create a branch, containing all of the commits from a given past commit to the current head in master?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create the branch. Afterwards, move `master` back 15 commits:

```
git checkout master # sane default
git branch your_branch
git reset --hard HEAD~15
```